# FineUploader S3 - Process original + scaled images as group in uploadSuccess endpoint

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, scaling, fine-uploader

I'm using the new FineUploaderS3 scaling functionality, but I have a question about how to handle these (separate upload) results as a group in the uploadSuccess endpoint. After every (scaled) upload of the same file the endPoint gets "called"

I know it's possible to set parameters in the uploadSuccess.params like:

```
uploadSuccess: {
    endpoint: "s3sign.php?success",
    params: {groupName:"aPerfectGroupName"}
},
```

But there is a problem when a new upload starts. These will get the same groupName at uploadSuccess. Also can't change via

```
$('#element').fineUploaderS3('setUploadSuccessParams', {groupName:"aBetterGroupName"});
```

callbacks (onComplete, onValidate, ...) because that will also change pending uploads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify the ID of the file you want to target as an additional parameter:

```
$('#element').fineUploaderS3('setUploadSuccessParams', {groupName:"aBetterGroupName"}, fileId);
```

This will limit the parameter to that specific file, and you can invoke this in a callback handler.  This is [documented in the setUploadSuccessParams section of the docs site](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods-s3.html#setUploadSuccessParams).